# Can any linear endomorphism of a vector space be written as a linear combination of invertible (or injective) operators?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of arbitrary dimension over a field $\mathbb{F}$.
Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear endomorphism of $V$.
Is it true that there exist $e \in \mathbb{N}^*$, constants $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{F}$ for $i \in [1,e]$, and invertible (or injective) operators $R_i: V \to V$ for $i \in [1,e]$ such that $T = \sum_{i=1}^e \lambda_i R_i$ ?

What if V is normed or a Hilbert space and the operators continuous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick idea when $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite and $\dim V<\infty$. Let $T$ be as in your statement, and consider $tF+I$, where $I$ is the identity and $t \in \mathbb{F}$. Note that $p(t)=\det(tF+I)$ is a polynomial in $t$, and $p(0)=\det(I)=1$. This way, there is some $t_0\neq 0$ such that $t_0F+I$ is invertible, and so $F=\frac{1}{t_0}(t_0F+I)-I$ is the difference of two invertible operators.